# Layout of fieldset inconsistent in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, fieldset

I am trying to use a fieldset legend as a label for a group of radio buttons. The HTML and CSS I have works fine in IE8&9, firefox and chrome. In IE7 the label appears over the radio buttons. In all other browsers the label appears to the left of the buttons. I am happy to add a conditional stle for IE7 but I cant figure out what would make this work.

The problem is replicated in the following markup

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .radiolegend {
      display: inline;    float: left;    width: 300px;
  }
  .fieldsetstyle {
      border: 0 none;    clear: left;    float: left;
        }

  </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
  <fieldset class="fieldsetstyle">
  <legend class="radiolegend">legend</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="r1" style="display: inline;" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">r1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="r2" style="display: inline;" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">r2</label>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you are not closing your <form> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ie7 conditional, then do this:

CSS

```
.radiolegend {
     float: left;    width: 150px;
}
.fieldsetstyle {
 border: 0 none;    clear: left;    float: left; width:300px;
}

.cb{
float:right;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
<fieldset class="fieldsetstyle">
<legend class="radiolegend">legend</legend>
    <div class="cb"><input type="radio" name="r1" style="display: inline;"/>r1</div>
    <div class="cb"> <input type="radio" name="r2" style="display: inline;"/>r2 </div>
    </fieldset></form>
```

Now, you need to change styling for the rest of the browsers too. Just remove `margin-top:-20px;` from `.cb`. You were wrapping text in `<input>` tag, it's not correct. `<input>` has to be self closing

Comment: thanks bobek. it looks like in ie7 its always putting a line break after the legend so using a negative margin on the radio buttons worked.